# Model for TCP server for single client

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, backgroundworker

I am new to C#, having mostly done web based coding in the past. I am creating a TCP server that will communicate with a single client. I know I need multiple threads because I do no want my program to block waiting on a connection (or reading data, sending, etc).

So far I have written a simple test application with a GUI and a class for the communication with the client. The main GUI class creates an instance of the communication class. I have the socket.accept call in a BackgroundWorker and I am trying to pass the connected socket back to the communication class in the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result. This has not been working. I can break in the DoWork method and see the socket is connected. I then set the DoWorkEventArgs.Result to the connected socket and attempt to pass it back to the communication class. In the RunWorkerCompleted method, the socket is no longer connected.

I may have the wrong idea about how to implement a TCP server for a single client. All the examples I have seen are designed for multiple clients, but I will be dealing with a single client. I have no control over the client and am simply trying to communicate with it.

How can I pass a connected socket from a BackgroundWorker back to the main class, or a better way to structure the code is what I need.

**Update:**

I do not control the client. It is an embedded Linux device. The protocol is very simple. A size header followed by data bytes.

Target is .NET 2.0. It appears that WCF is only available on .NET 3.0 and later.

**Update:**

My code will be sending commands to the client and receiving data back. My code will be a long running application that needs to continuously send/receive data.

Comment: Why do you need to program a socket manually? Don't you want to use WCF?

Comment: In general, there is no difference for server between single or multiple clients. You just can have higher load per client.

Comment: I recommend to try `Task Parallel Library` instead BGW.

Comment: @abatishchev - I am interested in seeing how to do this in WCF. Do you have a link you could recommend to show the basics of this? Thanks!

Comment: WCF gives you an easy way to build a server-client communication do not caring about network transport implementation. So it depends what is the client you're trying to communicate with. If it's a .NET app too, that's "piece of cake", harder if it's not.

Comment: Describe your client more. If you don't have a control over it, how can you control a protocol to communicate with it? Do you?

Comment: Okay I see. Try TPL to make multi-thread programming easier.

Comment: Why are you constrained to .NET 2.0?

Comment: .NET 2.0 is what is available on the PCs where the application will run. There is no other software installed that requires a higher version of .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked for other design ideas, here is my suggestion (I have used this pattern in Java and .NET) for the last 4 years in my projects and it proved working very well!)
The main idea is: You should not give your socket back to the main class. Your background worker should block on the socket waiting for the client, once it gets a connection it loops through and reads data from the client. The background worker will communicate received packets (binary format, don't parse the data here as it should be the main class' responsibility) to the main class through a [thread safe queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx). The main class can loop (or better use a [blocking queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)) and process any new messages coming from the client via the background worker.

This way you separate your code into two distinct layers. The worker, which is responsible of talking to the client and the main class which responsibility is to understand what the client says and optionally respond (still through the worker)

**EDIT** From your edit, I see that you are on .NET2.0. This version of the framework does unfortunately not have thread safe blocking queues as they are introduced in .NET4 I think. Still you can find many thread safe queue implementations around which are based on .NET2

Comment: Queue.Synchronized is available in .Net 2.0. [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized(v=vs.80).aspx Would I  notify the main thread with events, or have a loop checking the queue for new packets?

Comment: @JamesCrow Sorry my bad, what I meant is the blocking queues not thread safe queues :)

Comment: I should be able to use the BackgroundWorker ReportProgress method to notify the main thread that a new message has arrived. I am reworking my communication class to try this in .Net 2.0.